# php generated array in javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, json

I'm trying to plot some cities on Google's Geochart. This function works perfectly fine and will plot cities.

```
function drawMarkersMap() {
  var newInfo = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['City'],
   ['San Diego'],
   ['Los Angeles'],
   ['San Jose']
  ]);
```

While that's nice and all, I'm generating my cities from my database via php. So, let's just say we have this php array

```
<?php $city = array("San Diego", "Los Angeles", "San Jose"); ?>
```

Now here comes the part where I'm struggling. I can't seem to get a loop working properly so that I can output each city separately.

When I do this only the first city in the array(San Diego) will display and I understand why...I'm just showing that this method will at least print "something"

```
function drawMarkersMap() {
  var newInfo = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City'],
    ['<?php foreach($city as $location){ echo json_encode($location); } ?>']
]);
//options here
}
```

So, I'm attempting to loop through and print each item in the array using javascript but I don't seem to have the logic correct

```
function drawMarkersMap() {
  var newInfo = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City'],
    for(i=0;i<json_encode($city).count;i++){
     //some kind of print statement mixing php and javascript. I need help here please!
     }
]);
```

Here's the entire page

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Google Visualization API Sample</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<?
$city = array("San Jose","Los Angeles","San Diego");
foreach($city as $key=>$value) {
     echo "$value";
}  
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
 google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['geochart']});


function drawMarkersMap() {
  var newInfo = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City'],
['<?php echo json_encode($city);  ?>']
]);

var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

chart.draw(newInfo, {width: 556, height: 347, displayMode: 'markers', region: 'US-CA', resolution: 'provinces'});
}


google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);
</script>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to post what `json_encode()` actually outputs, not just the function in place. Your JSON is likely malformed, or not an array, but an object, which Google's functions might vomit over.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean. Can you please give me an example or modify what I have?

Comment: At the moment, all you've given is `<?php echo json_encode($city);  ?>`, which is useless because it's impossible to know if the string that `json_encode()` outputs is properly formed for the JS you plug it into. Instead of posting the PHP, please post the JSON string it outputs to the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php $city = array(array('City'), array('San Diego'), array('Los Angeles'), array('San Jose')); ?>

var newInfo = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php echo json_encode($city); ?>);
```

This recreates exactly the same array structure as your original script.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. I now see what @JamWaffles was talking about with my array set up improperly.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the [implode](http://tr.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php $city = array("San Diego", "Los Angeles", "San Jose"); ?>
    function drawMarkersMap() {
        var newInfo = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['City'],
        ['<?php echo implode("'],\n\t\t['",$city) ?>']
        ]);
    }
</script>
```

which will result in

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function drawMarkersMap() {
        var newInfo = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['City'],
        ['San Diego'],
        ['Los Angeles'],
        ['San Jose']]);
    }
</script>
```

As per request…

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php $city = array("San Diego", "Los Angeles", "San Jose"); ?>
    function drawMarkersMap() {
        var newInfo = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['City'],
        ['<?php foreach($city as &$c)$c=htmlspecialchars($c,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); echo implode("'],\n\t\t['",$city); ?>']
        ]);
    }
</script>
```

..although I should agree with the fact that using JSON is much practical :)

Comment: That works, until your values contain quotes or slashes... Let `json_encode` handle it.

Comment: @deceze I added an alternative to my post but I agree.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` does not necessarily help when you're trying to escape JSON syntax.

Comment: Maybe not, but you *are* trying to cobble together valid JSON/Javascript code, which means you need to escape for JSON/Javascript syntax, not HTML.